# The main page isn't refreshing automatically when I back from a question

Tags: feature-request

When I am in a question and I press the button of my browser courtship (Chrome) I go back to the main page, but it does not refresh, and I have to manually refresh (<kbd>F5</kbd>). Is it related to the site or my browser settings?

Comment: What do you mean by "browser courtship"?

Answer (score 3):

This is completely normal. When you use back, you get a cached version of the page that looks like the last time you had it open. *Every* web page does this. In fact, you *want* it to do this, for two reasons:

1. Faster load time.
2. So that things look exactly as you remember them, down to the same position of your scrollbar, the contents of any input fields, and the exact same dynamic content that you saw before.

This should not be changed, even if it were technically feasible to do so.

If you really want to refresh, then just hit refresh.